# ajax - Ajax vs document.getElementById().innerHTML

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to Ajax and web development in general. When I googled Ajax, a lot of sites (like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)) said that one of the key features or Ajax is that you can dynamically update content on the webpage without reloading it.

My question is this: can't you just do this by using `document.getElementById("...").innerHTML = "whatever you want it to change to"`? I know that with Ajax you can make requests to a webserver and whatnot. That is not my question. My question is that why do people claim that changing a webpage without reloading it is something special about Ajax when you can do it with normal JavaScript?

And also, in the link above, it said that with Ajax you can "request/receive data from a server - after the page has loaded". Why "after the page has loaded"? Is there another way to request/recieve data from a server while the page is still loading?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you get data from the server with innerHTML? The XMLHttpRequest is used for sending and retrieving data/content. InnerHTML is used to set content in the page. Ajax calls can be made when the page is loading.

Comment: W3Schools is not considered a good resource. To make the statement more accurate, it should read *"one of the key features of Ajax is that you can dynamically update content on the webpage **from a remote resource** without reloading it (the page)"*

Comment: To elaborate further, content loaded via AJAX may be injected into the page via `innerHTML` or other DOM manipulation methods. This is a better definition ~ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a misunderstanding of general client-side programming terms

Comment: Loading content by `innerHTML` is one way of doing AJAX. It's not the only way though but whatever way you decide to do it has nothing to do with AJAX but more with DOM scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is this: can't you just do this by using
>   document.getElementById("...").innerHTML = "whatever you want it to
>   change to"?

You can indeed change the inner markup of dom Element instances using this property.

> I know that with Ajax you can make requests to a webserver and
>   whatnot. That is not my question. My question is that why do people
>   claim that changing a webpage without reloading it is something
>   special about Ajax when you can do it with normal JavaScript?

Javascript is client side. Ajax is special in that it requests data from a server so you can use it in the client (javascript).
Javascript by itself (understand, without the `XmlHttpRequest` object) does not allow that. All you can do is client side dom manipulation, not knowing what's on the server side (which means, among other things, no access to shared databases)

> And also, in the link above, it said that with Ajax you can
>   "request/receive data from a server - after the page has loaded". Why
>   "after the page has loaded"? Is there another way to request/recieve
>   data from a server while the page is still loading?

Yes.

jsp, php, are two examples of server side languages. When you request http://page.php (for example), the server routes the request to the *.php interpreter. The code inside the page is then used to generate http headers and html content back to client. This is a round trip that happens every time a page is accessed. The page is first loaded using this system.
Ajax allows you to proceed with subsequent calls to any php script, while the page is already loaded.

Comment: Thank you for answering both of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

**ajax** is a way of loading data from the server without reloading the entire page, **innerHTML** is one way of injecting that data into the page...so **ajax** is a way of communicating with the server while, **innerHTML** is a way of manupilating the page.

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is the key deference between ajax and document.getElementById().innerHTML is

**AJAX**

AJAX will load the content when you want to change for the perticuler div and change the content the content are not stored in any where in current web page

**document.getElementById().innerHTML**

Where when you want to change the content without ajax then you need to store the content in any javascript variable or in hiddent html so it will load the content if you want to show or not.